Changing the Label of My Android App Already Uploaded to Play Store
I want to modify the label and, if possible, the icon of my app in the AndroidManifest.xml file. However, I'm concerned about violating any policies since the application is already live on the Play Store.
android:label="WeVe" <-- I want to change this
android:name="${applicationName}"
android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"> <-- And this

I'm looking for any guidance on how to safely make these changes without causing any policy violations.
Thanks in advance...

Stack Overflow is not customer support for an app store. That said, as far as I know, there is no significant difference between what you provide for an app name and icon for your initial upload to the store and for future uploads.

there is no issue changing your app name i have done it thousands of times

@CommonsWare I know that here isn't a customer support, but since I wasn't able to find a specific answer on the Play Store help page, I asked here. Anyways, thank you for your response!

@AlvaroDosio Yes, you can but make sure you still follow play console policy with new assets

@CommonsWare I think any questions regarding developers guidelines on the largest app store in the world are valid questions here and would need a developer to answer them. just my opinion.

Yes, you can change the label and the icon. You even can have multiple icons in the same app and change them on specific events. Also you can do experiments with multiple icons to chose the best one from the Google Play Store listing and from the actual app.
